# Execute a bat file as a specific user from php

Tags: php, batch-file

I have setup a web server and based on an HTTP request and need to execute a script as a different user.

So with regard to that, can I run HTTP as the user I need?

Or can I provide password non interactively and include something like below as the first line of the bat file.

```
runas /user:dmn1\user1 cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not a good idea to execute bat,sh or any other files from the commands can be tricked any ways.
You can use php's exec() to execute system commands.

Comment: How do you suggest I can run the exec command as the user I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute the command as a different user in the web server itself then I don't know how that is done but If you're trying to execute cmd via browser it can be achieved via .hta script which might not work with modern browsers except IE.

Answer (score 0):

Windows lacks built-in `sudo`-like functionality.

Your options are:

1. Use a 3rd-party tool such as [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) (requires specifying password in cleartext; might be a bit glithy sometimes) or [sudo for windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/) (allows webserver user unrestricted administrative access - insecure).
2. Run another web-server instance with the required user credentials on a different port and redirect requests there with .htaccess (this may be very insecure!)

You can only allow local access and use CURL from 1st webserver to make requests to the second one

3. Open "task scheduler" (`taskschd.msc`) and create a task, select the user as owner and enter their password.

To run the task use:
schtasks /run /s SERVERNAME /tn "SCHEDULEDTASKNAME"

You cannot pass parameters to the task directly - you can use a file but beware of overlaps if two people access the HTTP simultaneously

4. Run a BATCH file (or a python/powershell/autoit script) that monitors a directory for files. When a file appears, read parameters from there, run the task, and delete the file.

You can run the "server" script via task scheduler.

HTTP server should then create files in that folder with long random names.

If creating files is undesirable you may be able to use a named pipe or local TCP connection (netcat) or similar

5. write a system service yourself (you may need a tool such as [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) to actually make it run as a service )